# Changing default xml image on application load

Tags: android, xml

I have an android application that displays, by default, a series of ImageButtons using xml. The user changes the image based on their input. I am trying to display the changed ImageButtons the next time the user loads the app.

Example:
ImageButton starts as Android.png (loaded from default xml page)
User enters text
ImageButton is changed to Correct.png

The next time that the app loads I want Correct.png to display instead of Android.png. Is there a way to iterate through the ImageButtons before the app starts (the buttons are NOT created programatically) to set the source value for each one before the application loads?

Answer (score 0):

You can use findViewById(R.id.button_1) for each button and set it as needed. You'll then need to store which values it should have so that you can load these values and set the ImageButton source for each one. You can store it with either SharedPreferences or a SQLite database, depending on how much you have to change.

So, for example:

```
ImageButton b = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button_1);
b.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

You can load a drawable up for the checkbox so that you do it only once, which is more efficient, or you could setImageResource to R.drawable.correct, which would be a bit slower since I assume that the checkbox would probably be set for multiple images.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to perform this by using `SharedPreferences`.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("userpref", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);

String image = pref.getString("userchoice","no-image");

if(image.equeals("no-image")
{
     imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.android);
}
else
{
     //compare here your image
     imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.Correct);
}
```

And whenever user selects any other image, just edit your `preference` file by using following code.

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putString("userchoice","Correct.png");
```